# numpy element values do not change using indexing

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = [3,4,5,6]
b = [1,2,3]
adj = np.random.rand(10,10)
adj[a,:][:,b] = adj[a,:][:,b]  + 1000
```

Why do the element values of `adj` not change after `adj[a,:][:,b] = adj[a,:][:,b]  + 1000`?

Comment: Numpy is probably unable to get a view of that slice, so you end up with a copy. Modifying the copy does noe update the original

Comment: is there any way to modify the value using indexing?

Comment: If it's not performance critical, use a for loop,like `for bi in b: adj[a,bi]+=1000`.

Comment: I am curious why it does not change the value

Comment: This seems related: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2008-January/031101.html

Comment: @Sean Indexing multidimensional arrays always returns a copy. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, fancy indexing always returns a copy, not a slice. So you are modifying a copy that is later discarded.

When indexing several dimensions with arrays, this get broadcasted to a common shape, so any of the following will also do the trick for you:

```
a = [[3], [4], [5], [6]]
b = [1, 2, 3]
adj[a, b] += 1000

a = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 2, 3]
adj[a[:, None], b] += 1000
```

And of course, what should be your first option for your actual indices, although it will not work if they are not all consecutive integers:

```
adj[3:7, 1:4] += 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

So I suspect numpy can't return a view to that slice, so you are trying to modify a copy that gets garbage collected.

A solution is to use `meshgrid`. For example:

```
a = [3,4,5,6]
b = [1,2,3] 
adj = np.arange(7*7).reshape(7,7)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(a,b)
x,y = X.ravel(),Y.ravel()
adj[(x,y)]+=1000
```

Where `adj` is now:

```
array([[   0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6],
       [   7,    8,    9,   10,   11,   12,   13],
       [  14,   15,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20],
       [  21, 1022, 1023, 1024,   25,   26,   27],
       [  28, 1029, 1030, 1031,   32,   33,   34],
       [  35, 1036, 1037, 1038,   39,   40,   41],
       [  42, 1043, 1044, 1045,   46,   47,   48]])
```